# Integrating MoPub in android with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adbannerview, mopub

I want to integrate Twitter MoPub in android. I am using eclipse. Got lots of errors when importing their sdk. Do they have any support for eclipse or its just compilable in android studio ?

Download link: [Mopub in android](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/banner-interstitial-networks)

P.S. i don't have android studio. I have my project done in eclipse.

Comment: Actually i have some error with import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
which is may not be supporated by eclipse. So when i remove that the error automatically removed. But i want to know that is there is any other way to import mopub in eclipse. cause there is lot of import android.support.annotation.NonNull; in the project when importing in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions about your question.  Namely, that *this doesn't have anything to do with Twitter*.  I know MoPub keeps some of their documentation on Twitter, and I'm hoping that's what you're referring to.

So, if you are just asking "*Does MoPub for Android still work in Eclipse projects?*", then the **answer is "Yes"**.

I just used the latest and greatest MoPub Android SDK (3.4.0) in a new project in Eclipse, and it works just fine.  The sample on GitHub ([mopub-sample](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/tree/master/mopub-sample)) also works in Eclipse.

I prefer the [MoPub documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started) over their Twitter docs.  In this document, you should follow the steps, and because you're not using Android Studio, skip the steps from **Gradle Integration**, until you get to **Eclipse Integration**.  They have excellent screenshots and instructions for Eclipse.

Just make sure you finish the document, including **Adding the Support Libraries to Your Project**, and **Adding Google Play Services**.

If following this (GitHub) documentation doesn't work for you, please post follow-up questions with more specific details.

Comment: I'm hoping you can help me out @Nate, I'm having an awful lot of trouble trying to get the MoPub SDK integrated with Eclipse.  In fact, I have so many problems that I will have to post multiple SO question.  This is my 4th day trying to integrate.  Wonder if you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545399/mopub-integraton-problems-with-eclipse-build-path-jars, it would be much appreciated.