# MoPub Integration problems with Eclipse - Build Path / Jars

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, integration, mopub

On the [MoPub Integration Instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/getting-started) it says to go to Properties, Build Path and click on 'add jar' and then to **Click Add Jars and add the mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar from your download location**.

I may be misunderstanding this, but when I click on Add Jars, I can only select locations within projects that are situation within my Eclipse workspace.  Is it supposed to say 'Add External Jars'?........ It doesn't show this, it specifically shows the 'Add Jars' button highlighted, as you can see:

[image]

Or am I supposed to create a libs folder in my mopub-sdk project that I've imported and manually copy them in, then do 'Add Jars' and select them from there......

The docs say to 'Right click on ***your*** project' when adding these, however, the mopub-sdk that I've imported needs this Jar, so why do I have to add it to my project's build path when the MoPub-SDK is a dependency of my project - shouldn't I add it to the MoPub-sdk build path?!!

It's really confusing.  Anyone who's integrated MoPub using Eclipse?  This is now my 4th straight day attempting to integrate this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You actually answered your question: create a lib folder, copy the `jar` in there and add the dependency by `Add JARs`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi @Onik yeah I have done that and it works however I was trying to follow to instructions to the letter and that's **not** what it says to do - so wasn't sure if I was *supposed* to be doing that. The way I read it, it's asking me to simply click on add Jars and then go to my download location and select the relevant one which of course I can't do.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Not really @Nate, I just copied the jar files manually as I mentioned above - that's all I could do.

Comment: I'm receiving this problem as well. I actually added it as an external jar and it didn't work. Also, the three other .jar's that should be included with it in /libs/ are not there (I had to find it online). I think the tutorial is outdated, I am receiving multiple build errors for this.